# what's wrong with std::remove_if in this code

Tags: c++

> solution.cc:14:47: error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if(std::basic_string::iterator, std::basic_string::iterator, )'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    string s;
    std::getline(cin, s);
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isspace);

   // cout<<s;
    int len=s.length();
    len=len+90;
    bool temp;
    bool value[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
           int x=(int)s[i];
       if(value[x]!=1) value[x]=1;
    }
    for(int i=65;i<=90;i++)
     if(value[i]==1) {temp=true;continue;}
        else {temp=false;break;}
    if(temp) cout<<"pangram"<<endl;
    else cout<<"not pangram"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `isspace` defined, and if so, is it a function accepting a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried compiling your code in `g++ 4.9.1`. The exact error is:

> In function `int main()`:
>   error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if(std::basic_string::iterator, std::basic_string::iterator, unresolved overloaded function type)'

This didn't happen with your call to `std::transform` because you actually specified which `tolower` you're using.

`isspace` is defined both in the global namespace and in namespace `std`, so when you have `using namespace std`, and you write `isspace`, there's an ambiguity. To be specific, there's one overload in `<cctype>` and another defined in `<locale>`.

Just write `::isspace` and you're good to go.

Comment: @Shree worked then please remember to accept the correct answer